# Can a spring mvc action method return both a model to a view or xml or json?

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc

For a web application, I need to return a model to a view.

For a mobile application or API, I want to return xml or json.

Is it possible to do all of these using a single controller method, or do I have to duplicate this and create seperate API controller's etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring MVC 3.x you can do this with just the one controller method. The trick is to wire up the appropriate [`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations) in your Spring config. You can configure it to return the desired content type based on file extension and/or requested mime type.

It works best for methods that only add a single model attribute to the `Model`, otherwise the JSON/XML starts to get a bit ugly.

I often find its simpler/nicer to implement separate controller methods for my web service requests, as you can better control the format of the JSON/XML and the code is easier to maintain in the long term.

EDIT: Just to qualify my comment above, I find that complex JSP pages where there might be up to 5-10 model attributes added to the page, that the resulting JSON tends to be quite messy and you usually find you only really want 1-2 of those in the JSON. OTOH, simple pages with 1-2 models added work quite well.

Comment: so it is technically possible, but it isn't really practical is what your saying?

Comment: Depends on the application... its a very useful feature that I use a lot. I just added a few caveats to keep in mind. See my edits above.